# Как вывести информацию из JSON запроса в data tables Vuetify vue.js?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, vuetify

Делаю запрос на сервер с помощью axios в проекте vue.js. Получаю данные с сервера и пытаюсь их оформить в таблицу. Для начала пробую положит в одну колонку count, который равен 1. Таблица все равно пустая выходит.

Получаю следующие данные:

```
{
"data": {
"status": 0,
"response": [
{
"id": "1",
"owner": "l",
"status": "NEW",
"cfg": {
"count": 1,
"accept": [
"false"
],
"amount": {
"currency": "R",
"min": 1,
"max": "10"
},
"sender": {
"bank": {
"Agt": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "5555",
"name": [
"вязь"
],
"currency": "R",
"addr": {
"country": "RU"
}
},
"Acct": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "331"
},
"AgtAcct": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "301"
}
},
"client": {
"name": [
"Рог"
],
"Acct": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "331"
}
}
},
"recipient": {
"bank": {
"Agt": {
"type": "Othr",
"value": "04",
"name": [
"вязь"
],
"currency": "R",
"addr": {
"country": "RU"
}
},
"Acct": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "331"
},
"AgtAcct": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "301"
}
},
"client": {
"name": [
"Cor"
],
"Acct": {
"type": "Ot",
"value": "331"
}
}
}
}
```

Форма таблицы:

```
 <template>
       <div>

      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="arrayGetGroup"
        :items-per-page="5"
        sort-by="calories"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
       <template v-slot:top>
          <v-toolbar app color="primary" dark>
            <v-toolbar-title>Тест</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-divider
              class="mx-4"
              inset
              vertical
            ></v-divider>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          </v-toolbar>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>

        </div>
    </template>
```

Скрипт следующий

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

  export default {

    data: () => ({
      value: [],
      arrayGetGroup:[],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Номер',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'number',
        },
        { text: 'Сюда', value: 'arrayGetGroup.data.response[0].count' },
        { text: 'ММ', value: '' },
        { text: 'Ак', value: '' },
      ],
    }),
       mounted() {
        axios.post(cURL,
      {
        request_type: configuration,
        request: GetGroup
      })
      .then(response => (this.arrayGetGroup = response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  },

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Я положил .then(response => (this.arrayGetGroup = response)) в []. Получилось следующие  [response]. Все заработало, вопрос только как выдать перечь в колонку. Попробую на этапе запроса отрезать лишнее, если получиться напишу ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было простым. Может кому поможет. Надо было отрезать лишний кусок и тогда все получиться.

Пишем response.data.response

```
       mounted() {
        axios.post(cURL,
      {
        request_type: configuration,
        request: GetGroup
      })
      .then(response => (this.arrayGetGroup = response.data.response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  },
```

Тогда мы сможем написать следующие и получим перечь в столбец.

```
  headers: [
    {
      text: 'Номер',
      align: 'left',
      value: 'number',
    },
    { text: 'Сюда', value: 'id' },
    { text: 'ММ', value: '' },
    { text: 'Ак', value: '' },
  ],
```

Все оказалось просто и не надо было складывать в массив